# Send multiple files via Bluetooth to PC from gallery

Tags: bluetooth, 3.2-honeycomb, acer-iconia-a500

I wanted to send about 30 photos from Gallery to PC by selecting them all, clicking Share\Bluetooth and then selecting the target computer.

It didn't work. All transfers failed. But if I selected a single photo I have been able to send it. Around 99MB.

I've been able to workaround by zipping (thanks [ES File Manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop)!) and sharing the zip file only.

Is there something that I should know about sending multiple files via Bluetooth?

Comment: What are you using the send the files via bluetooth?

Comment: Plain Gallery's *share* button

Answer (score 1):

I use [Bluetooth File Transfer app](https://market.android.com/details?id=it.medieval.blueftp&hl=en). Its worked really well to send file to my computer. you can check multiple files to send at the same time and this has worked well for me. It also works well to send file back and forth between two phones if they both have it installed.